# Merge Audio and Video pipelines with gstreamer

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I have two different pipelines, one for video and one for audio. They both work independently but i'd like to merge them as a single one. I believe this is possible but i have no idea how to do such a thing :(

Here are my two pipelines:

Sender:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=1280,height=720,framerate=10/1' ! ffmpegcolorspace ! vpuenc codec=6 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.20.26 port=5000 

gst-launch alsasrc device=hw:2 ! audioconvert ! audioresample  ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink host=192.168.20.26 port=5001
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, payload=(int)96, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink

gst-launch udpsrc port=5001 caps="application/x-rtp" ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! alsasink
```

Moreover, anyone knows what would be the resulting sdp file so i can also open it in VLC if needed?

Any pointers would be of great help ;)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To merge the sender:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! \
    'video/x-raw-yuv,width=1280,height=720,framerate=10/1' ! \
    ffmpegcolorspace ! \
    vpuenc codec=6 ! \
    rtph264pay ! \
    udpsink host=192.168.20.26 port=5000 alsasrc device=hw:2 ! \
    audioconvert ! \
    audioresample  ! \
    alawenc ! \
    rtppcmapay ! \
    udpsink host=192.168.20.26 port=5001
```

To merge the receiver:

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, payload=(int)96, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! \
    rtph264depay ! \
    ffdec_h264 ! \
    xvimagesink udpsrc port=5001 caps="application/x-rtp" ! \
    rtppcmadepay ! \
    alawdec ! \
    alsasink
```

The SDP file would be of the form(generally, this is probably not exact):

```
v=0
c=IN IP4 <Receiver IP>
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96
a=recvonly
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
m=audio 5001 RTP/AVP 8
a=recvonly
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000/1
```

You should change the clock rates on the PCMA if it is two channels.

Also, you MAY need to add a `a=fmtp:96 sprop-parameter-sets=<your sprop-parameter sets in the caps>` after the video rtpmap line.

You should be able to get the full caps for both pipelines by launching it verbosely(`gst-launch -v`). This is so you can get the number of channels and clock-rate for PCMA and your `sprop-parameter-sets` for H264.

Comment: It's working but i'm getting this info when the stream starts. Should i be concerned?

    Dropped 2240 samples. This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly

Comment: Yeah, that is fine. You can modify the stream settings and your display sinks to improve performance and latency. If you are streaming back to the same device, I have noticed that setting the `sync` property on your display sinks helps but if the stream latency is satisfactory, then I would not change that setting.